# Не срабатывает атрибут DisplayName в grid'е winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Есть программа на winforms. Есть моделька:

```
class Users
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Имя")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Patronimyc { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Questionnaires> Questionnaires { get; set; }
        public Users()
        {
            Questionnaires = new List<Questionnaires>();
        }
        public virtual ICollection<SelectedAnswers> SelectedAnswers { get; set; }
    }
```

С помощью биндинг соурса в dataGridView запихиваю эту модель. И ожидал что столбец Name, будет называться Имя, но оно всё равно называется Name. Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так? Может я как то не так понял суть атрибута?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Столбцы генерируются автоматически? Постройте исполняемый пример: с `dataGridView` и `BindingSource`. Из кода модели проблемы не видно.

Comment: @defaultlocale, я на форме в правом верхнем углу тыкаю на стрелку и появляется контекстное меню гриды. Там есть пункт choose data source, вот там вот я выбираю биндинг соурс моей таблицы. И столбцы сами появляются в гриде.

Comment: @defaultlocale в вопросе появился скрин гриды.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Атрибут `DisplayName` используется при автоматической генерации столбца. Например, если Вы привяжете `DataGridView` таким образом:

```
List<User> usersList = ...//получаем список
dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView.DataSource = usersList;
```

, то таблица сама сгенерирует столбцы и проставит соответствующий заголовок.

В Вашем случае происходит следующее:

- дизайнер Visual Studio вытаскивает названия столбцов из таблицы в базе данных (не класса-модели);
- дизайнер прописывает названия столбцов `dataGridView` в файл соответствующей формы. Т.е. в файле `Form4.designer.cs` появляется что-то вроде:

  ```
  this.nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Name";
  this.nameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Name";
  ```
- во время исполнения код в дизайнере формы просто исполняется, соответственно столбцы заново не генерируются и атрибут не считывается.

Если короче, то проблема в том, что заголовки столбцов генерируются во время дизайна формы и далее не меняются.

Что можно сделать:

1. Редактировать заголовки на уровне формы. Судя по всему автогенерация в коде не используется, поэтому возможно будет легче настраивать заголовки с помощью дизайнера Visual Studio прямо в интерфейсе. Для этого нажмите правой кнопкой на `dataGridView` и выберите пункт «Edit Columns».
2. Генерировать источник данных на основе объекта. При выборе источника данных для таблицы можно выбрать новый источник типа «Object» и выбрать класс «Users». Тогда дизайнер сгенерирует столбцы, основываясь на классе и проставит нужный заголовок. Сделает он это только один раз и на последующие изменения `DisplayName` реагировать не будет.
3. После привязки данных самому с помощью рефлексии проходить по всем столбцам, определять соответствующие им свойства, находить атрибуты, проставлять заголовки.

Comment: default locale, сделал то что вы сказали, убрал биндинг соурс, добавил код `dataGridView2.DataSource = db.Questionnaires.Local.ToBindingList();` Не помогло, тот же результат, кстати у меня используется подход code first, база уже была, я дописал атрибут, не каких дополнительных миграций не делал, это имеет значения? Может что бы атрибут заработал нужны ещё какие либо телодвижения?

Comment: @Андрей атрибут не работает, т.к. столбец уже прописан в `Form4.designer.cs` и не генерируется. Попробуйте: `dataGridView2.Columns.Clear(); dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true; dataGridView2.DataSource = ...` Так он сгенерирует столбцы заново. При этом все изменения, сделанные во время дизайна будут потеряны, естественно.

Comment: default locale, извините, сам только что заметил, всё работает, просто я поставил атрибут у одной модели, а вытаскивал другую) 2 последние строки даже не понадобились.

Comment: @Андрей Т.е. вопрос изначально был неактуален?

Comment: default local, да, извините, только подскажите пожалуйста, я сделал у двух полей в модели Questionnaires 2 атрибута с русскими названиями `[DisplayName("Название анкеты")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Количество")]
        public int CountCompleted { get; set; }` И попробовал не полностью модель запихнуть в грид а вот так вот `dataGridView2.DataSource = db.Questionnaires.Select(q => new { q.Name, q.CountCompleted }).ToList();` То есть с использованием анонимных типов, так уже не получается вывести русские названия, так и должно быть? Или как то можно?

Comment: @Андрей насколько я понимаю не получится, т.к. у свойств анонимного типа уже нет атрибута.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо за помощь, закрываю тему.